# Copy all rows of data will fill color to new sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have a lengthy spreadsheet that is always being updated. When the task is complete the row of data will be filled with the standard color green. I want to be able to code a macro that can take all rows filled with the color green from the current sheet and paste them on a new sheet? Any ideas?

If this helps, the row numbers are not constant, they are always changing. The number of rows filled with green are not always the same.

Comment: You seem to have described what you want to do, and the algorithm necessary to do it, reasonably well.  What ideas are you looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can modify the code below as per your requirement.

```
Sub CopyGreenColoredRows()
Dim wsSource As Worksheet, wsDest As Worksheet
Dim i As Long, lr As Long, lc As Long, dlr As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set wsSource = Sheets("Sheet1") 'Source sheet with colored rows/Sheet to copy data from
Set wsDest = Sheets("Sheet2")   'Destination Sheet/copy the data to

'Clearing the destination sheet excluding headers before pasting new data
'Remove this line if not required
wsDest.UsedRange.Offset(1).Clear

lr = wsSource.Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
lc = wsSource.Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Column

With wsSource
    'Assuming Row1 is the header row
    For i = 2 To lr
        'The code assumes that the color applied is through the conditional formatting
        If .Range("A" & i).DisplayFormat.Interior.Color = 5287936 Then
            dlr = wsDest.Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row + 1
            .Range("A" & i, .Cells(i, lc)).Copy wsDest.Range("A" & dlr)
        End If
    Next i
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The code below does what you've described.  Notice in the animated .gif that Sheet2 starts off blank and then when run, just the green rows are copied over.  Of course, you'll need to modify for your exact situation.

[image]

```
Option Explicit
Sub transferGreen()
Dim sourceSh As Worksheet, destSh As Worksheet
Dim cell As Range, sourceR As Range, destR As Range
Set sourceSh = Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set sourceR = sourceSh.Range("A1")
Set sourceR = sourceSh.Range(sourceR, sourceR.End(xlDown))
Set destSh = Worksheets("Sheet2")
Set destR = destSh.Range("A1")
If destR.Offset(1, 0) <> "" Then Set destR = destR.End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0)
sourceR.Select
destSh.Activate
For Each cell In sourceR
  If cell.Interior.Color = 5287936 Then
    sourceSh.Rows(cell.row).Copy
    destSh.Rows(destR.row).Select
    destSh.Paste
    Set destR = destR.Offset(1, 0)
  End If
Next
End Sub
```